# progressbar html tag change

Tags: javascript, java, html

I'am working on progressbar that change the level when reaching some point.
The code.
I want to change the text under the progressbar when the progressbar reach 100 or above 90.
I could change it once but I want to go to next level, like this.
silver ==> gold ==> diamond ==> and more

```js
const step = 5;
var content=document.getElementById('mylevel').innerHTML;

const updateProgress = () => {
  const currentWidth = Number(document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width.replace( "%", ""));
  
  if (currentWidth>=100) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = `${currentWidth+step}%`;
  }

    if (currentWidth > 90) {
    
      document.getElementById("mylevel").textContent = "gold";
      document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = "0%";
    }
      if (currentWidth > 90 && content == "gold") {
    
      document.getElementById("mylevel").textContent = "diamond";
      document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = "0%";
    }
}

const restart = () => {
  document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```css
.progress {
  background-color: #ededed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#progressvalue {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightgreen;  
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div id="progressvalue"></div>
  
</div>
<p id="mylevel">silver</p>
<br />
  
<button type="button" onclick="updateProgress()">
  Update Progress
</button>
  
<button type="button" onclick="restart()">
  Restart
</button>
```

When the updateprogress is above 90 the silver change to gold, but I need to change again to diamond when the updateprogress is again above 90.
Am I putting the if condition in a wrong place, I tried many times.
I don't know what I'am missing and am new with JavaScript

I started the code but got help here to make it much better (80% of the code done by
**teresaPap** thanks)

Comment: I updated my answer since I had made a mistake! Also java (in the question tags) is a different language from javascript :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

After closer inspection it is an issue of `content` not updating you need to put it inside `updateProgress()` or it will forever remain the initial value.

```
const step = 5;
const updateProgress = () => {
    var content = document.getElementById('mylevel').innerHTML;

    //the rest of the code
```

I do however recommend you to improve your if statements. You only need one if for this task.

#### A better solution

A better solution would be something like this:
Add a hidden value to keep your level progress

```
</div>
<p id="hiddenlevel">0</p>
<p id="mylevel">silver</p>
<br />
```

and css:

```
#hiddenlevel {
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0%;
}
```

now that you have a hidden value you can wrap up all future ifs in a single one.

```
const levels = ["silver", "gold", "diamond"]
var mylevel = Number(document.getElementById("hiddenlevel").innerHTML);

if(currentWidth > 90 && mylevel < levels.length){
    document.getElementById("hiddenlevel").textContent = mylevel + 1;
    document.getElementById("mylevel").textContent = levels[mylevel + 1];
    document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = "0%";
}
```

and just like that you can just add a new level inside the `levels` array and it will be added without issues.

#### Update 2

Just noticed I made a mistake!
You don't need a hidden element for this: you might end up having to use hidden elements when using plugins, but it was completely unnecessary here :)

**Updated code**:

```js
const step = 5;
var mylevel = 0;
const updateProgress = () => {
  const currentWidth = Number(document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width.replace( "%", ""));
  
  if (currentWidth>=100) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = `${currentWidth+step}%`;
  }

    const levels = ["silver", "gold", "diamond"];

    if(currentWidth > 90 && mylevel < levels.length){
        mylevel = mylevel + 1;
        document.getElementById("mylevel").textContent = levels[mylevel];
        document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = "0%";
    }
}

const restart = () => {
  document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```css
.progress {
  background-color: #ededed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#progressvalue {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightgreen;  
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div id="progressvalue"></div>
  
</div>
  <p id="mylevel">silver</p>
<br />
  
<button type="button" onclick="updateProgress()">
  Update Progress
</button>
  
<button type="button" onclick="restart()">
  Restart
</button>
```

Comment: OMG, you are amazing.
Thank you so much.
I need to start to think wider, not just adding if-conditions.
And using the array is really smooth way.

Comment: Glad I could help :) I just noticed I didn't need a hidden element for this. I updated the snipplet!